# Creating custom printing for sympy.Derivative

Tags: python, sympy

Say I have a function `f(x,y)`, I want partial derivative of `f` w.r.t to `x` appear as
`\partial_{x}^{n} f(x,y)` so I created the following class

```py
class D(sp.Derivative):
    def _latex(self,printer=None):
        func = printer.doprint(self.args[0])
        b = self.args[1]
        if b[1] == 1 :
            return r"\partial_{%s}%s"%(printer.doprint(b[0]),func)
        else :
            return r"\partial_{%s}^{%s}%s"%(printer.doprint(b[0]),printer.doprint(b[1]),func)
```

which works fine, but goes back to default behavior when I evaluate the derivative by using `doit()` method. Say I have

```py
x,y = sp.symbols('x,y')
f = sp.Function('f')(x,y)
```

Then `sp.print_latex(D(f,x))` gives `\partial_{x}f{\left(x,y \right)}` which is correct, but `sp.print_latex(D(x*f,x).doit())` yields `x \frac{\partial}{\partial x} f{\left(x,y \right)} + f{\left(x,y \right)}`, which is the old behavior. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Also why am I not able to extend `sp.diff` in the same fashion?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you haven't overridden `doit` from the parent class and it returns plain `Derivative` objects rather than your subclass. Rather than creating a new `Derivative` class I suggest to create a new printer class:

```py
from sympy import *

from sympy.printing.latex import LatexPrinter

class MyLatexPrinter(LatexPrinter):
    def _print_Derivative(self, expr):
        differand, *(wrt_counts) = expr.args
        if len(wrt_counts) > 1 or wrt_counts[0][1] != 1:
            raise NotImplementedError('More code needed...')
        ((wrt, count),) = wrt_counts
        return '\partial_{%s} %s)' % (self._print(wrt), self._print(differand))

x, y = symbols('x, y')
f = Function('f')
expr = (x*f(x, y)).diff(x)

printer = MyLatexPrinter()

print(printer.doprint(expr))
```

That gives `x \partial_{x} f{\left(x,y \right)}) + f{\left(x,y \right)}`

You can use `init_printing(latex_printer=printer.doprint)` to make this the default output.

Comment: `init_printing(latex_printer=printer.doprint)` leads to the following error
`TypeError: doprint() got an unexpected keyword argument 'mode'`

Comment: You can use `lambda e, **kw: printer.doprint(e)` instead of doprint.

Comment: Thanks, It works but can you explain it a bit? I mean the error part.

Comment: The docstring for `init_printing` function explains that the `latex_printer` parameter needs to be a function that has a similar signature to the `latex` function which takes a bunch of keyword arguments.